# Apex Trigger Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I need to use the look up field which relates Contact and Account object in Trigger. I have lookup field Account__c on the Contact, but I cannot get the related Account for that contact when I write something like

`Map <Id,Account> acts = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name from Account where Id:=contact.Account__c]);`

it should get all related accounts in to acts, but it does not work..

How can I get related Accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a special case you don't need to create a relationship between contact and account, there is already a standard one. you can query it like so

```
try {
    Account parent = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :contact.AccountId];
} catch(QueryException e) {
    //list has no rows for assignment
    //means the account with Id could not be found
}
```

For more information about the api names you should look at the [wsdl](https://login.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp)

As an aside, you don't need to pass the results of this query to a map, any time you use Id = :idValue in a WHERE clause it is guaranteed that you will get exactly 0 or 1 result, and in the cause of 0 results a QueryException will be thrown.